# pass $SESSION variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

User inputs his phone number in an HTML form and then fills the google recaptcha, and presses a button. If the phone number section and recaptcha section are successfully completed, then a function named "sendOTP" is called from a javascript file, which uses the phone number to send an OTP to that number.  Everything seems to be working,  [[except that I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUzOn.png)]. I believe the phone number(which is represented as $_SESSION['Telephone'] is not passed successfully on to the javascript file to be used.
In this case, how can I pass on the variable to the javascript so that it can successfully send an OTP to the number?
Here is the validate-captcha.php code which validates the captcha, and if successful, it sends calls the sendOTP():

```
                    <?php
                session_start();
                $ph_number = '';
                    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
                    {
                        $secret = "key1";
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        //echo $ip;
                        $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$ip";
                        $fire = file_get_contents($url);
                        //echo $fire;
                        $numero = $_SESSION['Telephone'];
                        $data = json_decode($fire);
                        if ($data->success == true)
                        {   
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            var $("#mobile").val() = "<?php echo"$numero"?>";
                        </script>';
                            echo '<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
                            echo '<script src="verification.js">
                            
                            </script>';
                            
                            echo '<script>sendOTP()</script>';
                            return 1;
                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            
                            echo "Please fill captcha"; 
                            echo $numero;
                        }
                    } 
                ?>
```

Here's the javascript (verification.js) code:

```
                                            function sendOTP() {
                                            $(".error").html("").hide();
                                            var number = $("#mobile").val();
                                            if (number.length == 8 && number != null && (number.indexOf(5)==0 || number.indexOf(6)==0 || number.indexOf(9)==0)) {
                                                var input = {
                                                    "mobile_number" : number,
                                                    "action" : "send_otp"
                                                };
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    url : 'controller.php',
                                                    type : 'POST',
                                                    data : input,
                                                    success : function(response) {
                                                        $(".container").html(response);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                $(".error").html('Please enter a valid Hong Kong number!')
                                                $(".error").show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        async function verifyOTP() {
                                            var that = this;
                                            $(".error").html("").hide();
                                            $(".success").html("").hide();
                                            var otp = $("#mobileOtp").val();
                                            var input = {
                                                "otp" : otp,
                                                "action" : "verify_otp"
                                            };
                                            if (otp.length == 6 && otp != null) {
                                                const handlerA = async function() {
                                                    var res = false
                                                    try {
                                                        await $.ajax({
                                                            url : 'controller.php',
                                                            type : 'POST',
                                                            dataType : "json",
                                                            data : input,
                                                            success : function(response) {
                                                                $("." + response.type).html(response.message);
                                                                $("." + response.type).show();
                                                                if (response.type=='success') {
                                                                    res = true
                                                                } else if (response.type == 'error') {
                                                                    res = false
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            error : function(response) {
                                                                console.log ('fail')
                                                                //console.log(data)
                                                                alert("Error encountered. Please try again later.");
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                        return res;
                                                    } catch (err) {
                                                        console.error( err )
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                const handlerB = async function () {
                                                    await $.ajax({
                                                        url : 'submission.php',
                                                        type : 'POST',
                                                        data : input,
                                                        dataType : "json",
                                                        success : function(response) {
                                                            $(".container").html(response);
                                                        }   
                                                    })
                                                }
                                                let $resultA = await handlerA()
                                                // Now exec B
                                                if ($resultA == true) {
                                                    let $resultB = await handlerB();
                                                    $resultB;
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                $(".error").html('You have entered wrong OTP.')
                                                $(".error").show();
                                            }
                                        }
```

If necessary, then here is the PHP file(controller.php) where the sendOTP() function is defined:

```
                                    <?php
                                session_start();

                                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
                                require ('textlocal.class.php');
                                include('config/db_connect.php');
                                class Controller
                                {
                                    function __construct() {
                                        $this->processMobileVerification();
                                    }
                                    function processMobileVerification()
                                    {
                                        switch ($_POST["action"]) {
                                            case "send_otp":
                                                $mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];   
                                                $sender = 'me';
                                                $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
                                                $_SESSION['session_otp'] = $otp;
                                                $message = "Your One Time Password is " . $otp;
                                                $numbers = array(
                                                    $mobile_number
                                                );
                                                $url = 'https://www.something.hk/s.php';
                                                $data = array(
                                                    "user" => "user",
                                                    "pass" => "password",
                                                    "to" => $mobile_number,
                                                    "from" => $sender,
                                                    "unicode" => 0,
                                                    "mess" => $message,
                                                    "otp" => 1,
                                                    "schtime" => 0
                                                );
                                                // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
                                                $options = array(
                                                    'http' => array(
                                                        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                                                        'method'  => 'POST',
                                                        'content' => http_build_query($data)
                                                    )
                                                );
                                                $context  = stream_context_create($options);
                                                $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
                                                if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
                                                require_once ("verification-form.php");
                                                break;

                                            case "verify_otp":
                                                $otp = $_POST['otp'];
                                                $MPF_account = $_SESSION['MPF_account'];
                                                $Telephone = $_SESSION['Telephone'];
                                                $Gender = $_SESSION['Gender'];
                                                $Job = $_SESSION['Job'];
                                                $Monthly_salary = $_SESSION['Monthly_salary'];
                                                $Existing_loan = $_SESSION['Existing_loan'];
                                                $Residential_Type = $_SESSION['Residential_Type'];
                                                $Existing_loan = $_SESSION['Existing_loan'];
                                                $Job_Type = $_SESSION['Job_Type'];
                                                $Existing_loan_amount = $_SESSION['Existing_loan_amount'];
                                        
                                                if ($otp == $_SESSION['session_otp']) {
                                                    unset($_SESSION['session_otp']);
                                                    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success", "message"=>"Thank You! Your form has been successfully submitted." ,"MPF_account"=>$MPF_account,
                                                    "Telephone"=>$Telephone,"Gender"=>$Gender,"Job"=>$Job,"Monthly_salary"=>$Monthly_salary,"Existing_loan"=>$Existing_loan,
                                                    "Residential_Type"=>$Residential_Type,"Existing_loan"=>$Existing_loan,"Job_Type"=>$Job_Type,"Existing_loan_amount"=>$Existing_loan_amount
                                                ));
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"error", "message"=>"Mobile number verification failed"));
                                                }
                                                break;
                                        }      
                                    }
                                }
                                $controller = new Controller();
                                ?>
```

Also, here is the HTML form that was used at the first stage:

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>OTP SMS</title>
                  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
                  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
                  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                  <script src="verification.js"></script>
                  <?=(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && $data->success) ? "<script>sendOTP()</script>" : ""?>
                </head>

                <body>
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                    <form action="validate-captcha.php" id="frm-mobile-verification" method="POST">
                      <div class="form-heading">Mobile Number Verification</div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <input type="number" id="mobile" class="form-input" placeholder="Enter the 8 digit mobile" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Telephone'] ?>">
                      </div>
                      <div method="post" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key2"></div>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                  <script src="verification.js"></script>
                </body>

                </html>
```

Comment: What is the resulting client-side code created by this?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: yes. Everything is what I expected it to be. All that is required now is that the javascript file takes the $_SESSION['Telephone'] and uses it in the controller.php to send the OTP code to the number

Comment: Can you show what that resulting code is?  The errors that you're showing in that image refer to specific JavaScript code, what is that code?

Comment: it refers to the javascript code of "verification.js" which I already included.

Comment: If you take a moment to look at the error(s) you're showing us, you will observe that there are *two* of them.  The one which comes first is *not* in `verification.js`.  So where is it?  What code does it refer to?  In your browser's debugging tools, follow that error to the code which is producing it.  What is that code?  The error is telling you that the code has a syntax error.

Comment: Don't pass `$_SESSION` variable to a client, the information it contains should be kept in the server only.

Comment: What is this meant to accomplish?: `var $("#mobile").val() = ...`  That's not a syntactically valid variable name.  All of your other variable names are simple words, which is what variable names should be.

Comment: *"I believe the phone number [...] is not passed successfully on to the javascript file to be used."* - Belief may be of some comfort, but debugging and observation are going to be far more useful.  Observe your client-side code in the browser and see what the actual problem is.  *"Everything is what I expected it to be."* - Your code has syntax errors.  If that was your intent and it meets your expectation then you should probably re-visit some introductory JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: So initially I made the code without including the captcha, in which case the HTML form button had an onclick = sendOTP() and everything worked fine. Based on that, I believe that if the input to the form can be passed to the js file, then it should work fine as well. Previously, $("#mobile").val() was the value that was received from the HTML form.

Answer (score 2):

#### Fixing JavaScript output by PHP

You have this in your code:

```php
var $("#mobile").val() = "<?php echo"$numero"?>";
```

This is not valid JavaScript you are outputting.
`var` must be used with a variable name. That is what the syntax error is supposed to tell you.
What you intended is to set the value. Look at the jQuery documentation on how to do that:
https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

That leaves us with this solution...

```php
$("#mobile").val("' . $numero . '");
```

...which puts the value for `$numero` from the PHP variable into the input field with id `mobile`.

#### Fixing the order of JavaScript

Your PHP code now outputs this:

```php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var $("#mobile").val() = "' . $numero . '";
    </script>';
  echo '<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
```

Notice you add jQuery after you do `$("#mobile").val()`, which requires jQuery. So you have to add jQuery first (includes the fix from before):

```php
  echo '<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#mobile").val("' . $numero . '");
    });
    </script>';
```

Notice I also added a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler to load the HTML document first before calling the JavaScript.

#### Please respect the comments

Please read the comments again. They were trying to help you discover the JavaScript error there. You were insisting your code is okay - or at least your wording indicated you don't see the problem at all - you "just need the solution".
They were hinting you should rethink and you were showing no signs of understanding the syntax error is fault of your code.

You are supposed to go "Oh maybe the syntax *is* wrong, I will check the documentation again how to do that".

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did help to get rid of the first error (which was a syntax error). However, the second error remains. I looked around stack overflow to find the cause, and what seems to me is that var number in the javascript file is still empty, meaning that the $numero was not successfully passed to the javascript.

Comment: You should have gotten errors. Please share them. I added another part to the answer, because I noticed you are trying to change the value before adding jQuery - jQuery has to be added first before using it. I also updated the answer regarding the value, that should be correct now. Do you understand what I mean in the answer?